# Downloading a file from the command line using Python

Tags: python, http, download, command-line-interface

I am looking for a quick way to download a file via HTTP, using a Python one-liner from the command line (similar to the functionality of `wget` or `curl`). The idea is to enable a quick copy/paste to download `distutils` on Windows.

I know of one solution (see my answer below). I'm interested in other solutions that consider the following:

- Concise
- Most "Pythonic" solution
- Compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3
- Cross-platform
- Can deal with large files efficiently
- No dependencies (we're fetching `distutils` here. It's unlikely we'll have access to `requests` at this stage)
- Correctly handles various HTTP headers, such as `Content-Disposition`

Comment: Distutils and setuptools have merged. To fulfill my original goal: `c:\python27\python.exe -c "from urllib import urlretrieve; urlretrieve('https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py', 'ez_setup.py')" & c:\python27\python.exe ez_setup.py`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest solution I could come up with would be:

```
try:
    from urllib.request import urlretrieve
except ImportError:
    from urllib import urlretrieve

urlretrieve('http://example.org', 'outfile.dat')
```

`urlretrieve` takes care of downloading the resource to a local file and can deal with large files.

It, however, ignores `Content-Disposition` headers. If you want that to be considered, you'd need to use `urlopen` and parse the response headers yourself. `Content-Disposition` isn't a HTTP standard header, so I doubt you will find much support for it in the Python HTTP libraries...

Comment: The main thing this doesn't have is the ability to run it via a CLI one-liner. I'll mark this as correct since it can be split into two statements, one for python2 and one for python3, that can handle large files and be run as a one-liner.

Comment: Python 2: `python -c "from urllib import urlretrieve; urlretrieve('http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py', 'distribute_setup.py')"`

Comment: Python 3: `python3 -c "from urllib.request import urlretrieve; urlretrieve('http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py', 'distribute_setup.py')"`

Comment: Dwurf has the answer correct: 
    the original question wanted this as a one-liner suitable for invoking directly from the command line. (And coincidentally, the search for which brought me here).

Comment: Content-Disposition is a standard now. If recent python releases implemented it, well, I don't know. 
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html --> 19.5.1 Content-Disposition

Answer (score 6):

My solution is:

```
python -c "import urllib; print urllib.urlopen('http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py').read()" > distribute_setup.py
```

Comment: this is really bad for large files, and it only works on python2. not really what the OP wanted.